# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Fails on Partially Offline Deployment Group

Tags: azure-devops

I'm currently using Azure DevOps for CI/CD and have set up a deployment group with multiple target machines. Some of these machines are scheduled to go offline during the night . However, I've noticed that when even one of these machines is offline, my release pipeline fails to deploy to the entire group, including the online machines. The error message I receive is: "Deployment Group deployment configuration settings are not met."

My goal is to have the release pipeline deploy successfully to the online machines, even if some machines in the deployment group are offline.

Is there a configuration setting or workaround in Azure DevOps to handle this scenario? How can I ensure that the pipeline continues to deploy to online machines without being halted by offline ones? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If the machine is turned off during the pipeline running, the run will fail absolutely.  You can consider to add a script([rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)) in local machine schedule, set the machine tag as `OFF` when it's down(default is ON),  on pipeline deployment task, add tag `ON` on deployment to only deploy to the online machines, so it will exclude the offline machines. It's not ideal but should work.

Comment: Yeah ended up doing pretty much exactly that, using a JS script via the rest api to patch in "Online" tags to all online machines as the first stage of the deployment, then filtered the deployment group for that flag. It works quite well, though it is a shame that we have to do such workarounds, when the machine status is in literally in the same object as the tags, it would be 0 effort for microsoft to add an option for this

Comment: Glad to know it works. You can raise a user voice ticket in [Developer Community](aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas) to ask the feature. Meanwhile, in order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested to post a reply and [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could check if you have enabled the `one target at a time` setting and test again.

[image]

Comment: How does this address the core problem? If a machine in the deployment group is offline, the pipeline will fail. This is going to happen **regardless of whether the deployment is happening in paralllel or not**.